# Adding Check box on Model Value condition in MVC Telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using teleik grid in MVC3, i am binding my grid data with model response value.
now my requrement is i have to add a checkbox in only those columns which status are completed.

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.response)

     .Columns(columns =>
          {                      
              columns.Bound(grid => grid.CaseStatus).Width(80);

              columns.Bound(grid => grid.CaseID).Title("").Format("<input  type='checkbox'name='checkedRecords' value='{0}'  id ='{0}'/>").Encoded                          (false).Width(5);
          })
```

i am binding my check box like this but i have to bind checkbox only with those rows, which status will completed.

please let me know how to check the value of CaseStatus here.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use columns.Template to add checkbox. Like here:

```
columns.Template(o =>
            {
                %>
                    <input name="checkedRecords" type="checkbox" value="<%= o.CaseID %>" 
                    <% if (checkedRecords.Contains(o.CaseID)) {

                        %> checked="checked" <%
                      } %>
                   />
                <%
            }).Title("").Encoded(false).Width(5);
```

See more details here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/checkboxesserverside